# Update text watcher based on other events

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-checkbox, android-event

In one of my screen i am using text watcher to check value against a range and for invalid range color of text is being changed.
Now there is one more requirement.
Along with EditText i need to use CheckBox to set completely different range.

The problem i am facing is that changing the checkbox value requires to call afterTextChanged in which i have put all validations for both set of ranges.

So basically my requirement is to update textWatcher anyhow so that afterTextChanged get called after i change value of checkbox.

I get a strange feeling that i am forgetting something very simple here,if so please let me know.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps move your code from the callback in the textWatcher and put it into another function ie

```
private void checkRange() {
    // do checks here
    String color = text.getEditableText().toString();
}
```

and call this method from your textWatcher and from the listener on the checkbox.

Comment: Hi,
Actually it is lots of code and i have intentionally not put the same code in checkbox because it is only used to set the range.
You may be right,but i really want to know it by this way if it is possible or not.Still thanks for your reply.